# User not seeing the editor controls

Tags: support, editor, google-chrome

User [Berkly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8885777/berkly) wrote this in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661758/trouble-passing-my-data-from-class-to-class-using-intents):

> For some reason it wont let me edit it or add code as "code"

Berkly posted this image in a subsequent comment:
[image]

Indeed, on this Windows Chrome screenshot, the editor buttons are missing.

Any way to help Berkly?

Comment: Without any more info, I doubt it. My best guess is that it failed to load for some reason, and he didn't try to reload.

Comment: Open dev tools, refresh window, check the console.